# 404 not found for pdf asset file (HTML) why?

Tags: html

I have the following html in my `resume.html` file.

```
  <a target="_blank" href="./resume.pdf">Download PDF Version</a>
```

When I view this locally on my computer and try to download the pdf, a new tab is opened with my pdf available for download. That is the behavior I want.

However, by deploying my files and clicking on this button, I have the following error:

[image]

What could be the reason that my file cannot be found. Could it be http/https? or some other issue. This should be a no brainer but I can't get this to work. Why can't it be found, it is able to be located when I open it locally.

Comment: remove the "./" from the beginning of  href="./resume.pdf" it's needed only on the filesystem

Comment: @AliAli thanks for the reply but unfortunately I get the same issue. For some reason its unable to find this file.

Comment: Do you have your resume.pdf file at the root of your site?

Comment: I saw your site. put your resume.pdf file inside your assets folder and change href to be href="assets/resume.pdf"

Comment: Unfortunately still the same problem. This file just doesn't want to be found. I can find any other asset file in the url like this one for example `http://nervous-giraffe.surge.sh/assets/images/profile.jpg` (default image) but I can't get this pdf file. I wonder if pdf files are treated differently. I've tried the `download` attribute approach too but still no luck (https://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute)

Comment: Please check you .htaccess file if you allow users to access .pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found was a simple fix in hosting. I switched from the free service `surge` onto github pages and the issue resolved itself.

For more information regarding surge and pdfs. Refer to the following link.

[Surge hosting and pdf issues](https://github.com/sintaxi/surge/issues/257)